# Windows - Force Wi-Fi to N mode

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I bought a month ago the [D-Link DWA-160 Xtreme N Dual Band USB Adapter](http://www.dlink.com/ca/en/home-solutions/connect/adapters/dwa-160-xtreme-n-dual-band-usb-adapter) and I wonder about the speed. I have a 60Mbps but the speed is never above 300Kbps when I browse Internet or download something. Even from Microsoft or Apple (the fastest server I found). Now on Windows 8, we can see the Wi-Fi stats in Task Manager, there they are:

[image: Wi-Fi]

Notice the red rectangle. The signal is 3/5 and I'm about 5 meters far from my router. An Apple Time-Capsule. Also, the connection type is 802.11g, I want N.

I made this config in my Device Properties:

[image: Wi-Fi Config]

Does anyone figured out to force the 802.11n in Windows? (Windows 8 preferably)

Comment: It's written just below the first image! In the third sentence. ;)

Comment: What WiFi security mode are you using? If it's not WPA2/AES, that's probably your problem.

Comment: It's indeed WPA2/AES.

Comment: Okay, I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: It doesn't matter, I don't expect a response very fast!

Answer (score 1):

I have read that if a device that can only run at G speeds connects to the AP,it will force the router to transmit only at G speeds in order to be compatible. This means that anything connecting to the same AP will be forced to use G speeds as well. I have this issue with my house,as my laptop can use N speeds and my PS3's internal receiver is only able to use G and as such,my laptop is limited to G as well. If there are any devices connecting to you AP that can only pick up only G speeds,that is likely your issue.

Comment: I have an Apple AirPort Extreme. It is Dual-Band so G and N network run parralelly.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with my intel radio on my laptop and PC. I could not get Windows to use 11n to connect to my router even though Linux and Android would. The Linux box even had the same hardware as the Windows PC. What finally worked for me was moving my router's channel to a less congested channel, and then Windows started using 11n!